# Update on the projected coin inflation for ethereum?

Tags: mining

I've seen this question:
[What is Ethereum's inflation rate? (how quickly will new ether be created)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12501/what-is-ethereums-inflation-rate-how-quickly-will-new-ether-be-created)

but the answers are vague and out-of date

I know that Bitcoin is halving and all coins will be mined at some point. But with ethereum the number of coins to be mined is less clear. What is the best determination of the projected outstanding coins for ethereum?

What is the latest on this topic? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum has no maxiumum limit of coins that can be mined like bitcoin, the purpose of ether is to use it in order to pay for gas.

Currently there is a reward of 2 ETH per block but it will decrease slowly to encourage in switching to ETH2

Ethereum was designed for business use, not just a p2p currency like bitcoin, the reason of not having a maximum amount of coins to be mined is for keeping the price stable and worth it in order to make transactions.